# Can water seep into my laptop through the sides of the trackpad?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

If I use the my laptop while my hands are (very) wet, will the water get into the insides of the computer through the gaps at the side of the trackpad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - capillary action is strongest in small gaps like the one surrounding the glass trackpad and the unibody frame. That liquid would likely seep and pool on top of the battery.

Comment: and what's next?

Comment: If i hypothetically got it any way wet - I would power off immediately. get a large towel and place it over the keyboard and trackpad (maybe twice), close the lid and tip the rear of the mac gently over to me keeping the battery lowest. I'd let it sit for half an hour lying with the glass screen lowest on the table - then open the screws to see how bad it wasn't. Hypothetically, of course.

Comment: If any significant water came out to the towel - I would take it in - the tools to remove the battery are specialized and i'd rather know sooner than later how much water got in and where it landed. The people that work for apple will be nice to you - you won't be the first one with a wet mac. They'll know what your best options are and it'll be up to you whether to fix it now or wait based on if anything even sensitive got wet. Who knows - it might be totally fine and you don't have to worry.